# Cannot set recommended resolution to monitor

Tags: display, resolution

I got new monitor hp la2205 with recomended resolution 1680 x 1050 
But when I'm trying to set resolution via display properties , the option 1680 x 1050 does not appear in list of modes

Graphics card : ATI Radeon HD 3450
OS : Windows XP sp3

What can be the issue ? 
Thanks

Comment: Anyone else think this is a strange native resolution for this monitor?

Comment: @Chris Not according to Wikipedia: WSXGA+ stands for Widescreen Super eXtended Graphics Array Plus and is a computer display standard. A WSXGA+ display is commonly used on Widescreen 20", 21", and popular 22" LCD monitors from numerous manufacturers (and a very small number of 19" widescreen monitors), as well as widescreen 15.4" and 17" laptop LCD screens like the Thinkpad T61. The resolution is 1680×1050 pixels (1,764,000 pixels) and has a 16:10 aspect ratio. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WSXGA%2B#WSXGA.2B_.281050p.29

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**What graphics card is your computer using?** My first thought is that your graphics card can't deliver that resolution, or that the correct drivers aren't installed.

So you should first check whether your computer is even capable of delivering that resolution. (You can also update your question with information about your computer/graphics card - then fellow SuperUsers can help you determine if the hardware is good enough.)

If the hardware is good, then check if the correct software is in place and properly configured. Tell us if you're using Windows, and which Windows version that is.

**Update:** Well, your card [certainly can provide](http://www.amd.com/us/products/desktop/graphics/ati-radeon-hd-3000/hd-3400/Pages/ati-radeon-hd-3400-specifications.aspx) this resolution. Next, download the latest ATI display driver (here is a [direct link](http://support.amd.com/us/psearch/Pages/psearch.aspx?type=2.4.1&product=2.4.1.3.15&contentType=GPU+Download+Detail&ostype=Windows+XP+-+Professional%2fHome&keywords=&items=20)) and see if that helps!

Comment: +1 for suggesting drivers. Thats probably the problem. Out of interest, what is the maximum resolution you can select?

Comment: @Connor: Well, according to the specs (see link above), the card "supports 18-, 24-, and 30-bit digital displays at all resolutions up to 1920x1200 (single-link DVI) or 2560x1600 (dual-link DVI)" on two displays. Impressive.

Comment: @torbengb I probably should have worded it better, but I was asking the user who posted the question. My thinking being that, the max resolution you can normally achieve using the basic Windows drivers is about 800x600 or 1024x768, so if that was the highest it would let him select, it is almost definitely a driver problem (or lack thereof).

Comment: Maximum resolution I can set is 1400 x 1050

Comment: Thanks to all : after upgrading driver I can see improvement - the resolution was set when connecting without KVM switch

Comment: Works also via KVM switch

Answer (score 1):

Also check if your monitor has been correctly detected. Check Device Manager > Monitors. If it has detected correctly it will display as the name and model no of your monitor, if not they it will display as Generic PnP Monitor. In this case you also will need to install the drivers that came with your monitor so that it can detect correctly along with it's resolution.

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar problem and wasted a day fighting it.  Hopefully this will help someone else in the same predicament.  My configuration was
Windows 7 Ultimate, 32-bit
HP dc7700 with built-in Intel graphics adapter
Brand new Dell u2410 LCD monitor connected to the computer via a VGA cable

The problem was that I could select certain resolutions on the monitor (e.g. 1792x1344), but when I tried to set the monitor to its native resolution (1920x1200), I would get a black screen with a less then helpful message telling me to set the resolution to one of the supported resolutions such as "1920x1200 @ 60Hz", which is what I was doing in the first place.

I believe one of the following two things fixed the problem:

1. Turning the power off on both the computer and the monitor and then turning power on on the monitor first and then on the computer second. (simple, try that first)
2. Booting the system in the "safe" mode, uninstalling (but NOT deleting!) the driver for the Graphics adapter (in my case it was labeled as an Intel Chipset), shutting the computer and starting Windows in normal mode.  When the computer booted it recognized the graphics adapter as "new" hardware and re-installed the driver.  Then I was able to set the monitor resolution to 1920x1200.  Note that during all this, the monitor was connected to the computer.

Earlier in the process, I did confirm the 1920x1200 resolution worked on the monitor by connecting it to another computer (Windows XP) using the same VGA cable.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using DVI or VGA cables to connect the screen?  I will assume VGA.

If so are you using a display switch box? If so remove it, otherwise are you using the VGA cable that came with the screen or possibly a very old one?  My thought here is that the DDC (effectively the resolution plug 'n' play) pins aren't connected.

Answer (score 0):

If the monitor is connected via VGA, you should try to connect rather via DVI.

Otherwise, you can try and use [PowerStrip](http://entechtaiwan.com/util/ps.shtm).

See this tutorial how to [Customize monitor resolution settings with PowerStrip](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-1046725.html), which says:

> Two primary software components, the
>   video driver and the monitor driver,
>   affect the quality, resolution, and
>   color depth of the image on your
>   screen. As I mentioned, PowerStrip
>   doesn’t replace your video driver; it
>   supplements it. So Windows still uses
>   the original video driver. One of the
>   ways that you can use PowerStrip to
>   supplement the video driver is to
>   create custom resolutions.

See also this [Powerstrip guide](http://www.ramelectronics.net/powerstrip.ep) from which I quote:

> Powerstrip is very powerful, but also
>   quite capable of causing your computer
>   and display to stop "communicating"
>   properly, this could cause the display
>   to start rolling, doubling or
>   generally freaking out. It is
>   important that you don't freak out as
>   well. It is recommended that you know
>   how to start up your computer in
>   "Safe" mode and "VGA" mode, uninstall
>   and reinstall drivers and get around
>   in "Device Manager" if you wish to use
>   this software.

I would also recommend having backups to your data and creating a system restore point, before installing and using it.